# Add image to a navigationItem's title

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I'd like to add a logo to the left of my title on my navigation bar. The title property seems to only take an NSString.  What's the best way to add an image to the navigation bar?

Comment: Just curious so I can learn to avoid the same deficit in the future, but why did my question get marked down?

Comment: I's be curious to see also.  Seems like a reasonable, if narrow, question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can replace the title view with an image like this:

```
navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"title_bar.png"]];
```

Comment: Correct; minor nitpick, this has a memory leak--be sure to autorelease the UIImageView.

Comment: Anyone know the maximum and ideal dimensions for this view?

Answer (score 2):

Set `UINavigationItem.titleView` to a *custom view* (or just a straight UIImageView).

Answer (score 0):

You can customize `navigationItem.titleView`, class of UIView