# navcontroller - Setting up Navigation Item as image

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I would like to setup the navigation controller bar button item to be an image.

I have read the following - [Add image to a navigationItem's title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328352/add-image-to-a-navigationitems-title)

I understand how to setup this as an image. I am actually looking to set this up as the setting cog, within the bar button item (like a cog icon). I have seen this before in other apps, I would like to know if there is a default style to initialise for this or normally if this is achieved by the image route as above.

If this is above, does anyone know where this (kind of) default image styled icon is available, or would I need to make one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `initWithCustomView` option of `UIBarButtonItem`? A sample code will look like the below line.

```
UIBarButtonItem *aButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"]]];
```

Another way to do this is,

```
UIBarButtonItem *aButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buttonTapped)];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use storyboard, you can directly:

1. Drag a `Button` in the navigation bar instead of a `Bar Button Item`. It will automatically create a `Button Bar Item` for you with a `Button` inside it.
2. Enter a title for the `Button Bar Item`
3. Set an image for the `Button` with a `Custom` type.

It should works.